# current transformer and primary positioning inside window

Tags: electromagnetism

I am designing a setup that is a little convoluted. but it's on purpose. The point is to make a toroidal current transformer act as an electromechanical pickup. Just for musical experimentation and as a practical exercise.

So,
I would use a tensioned conductive string as a primary, with one turn (cable going straight at the center of the toroid). The primary would pass an arbitrary DC current, let's say 1A

I wound two windings over the core. one CW the other CCW.
Both windings are 26 turns, Both are wound opposite to each other. Both windings use 1/4 of the winding window.
The theory is, if I pluck the string with parallel motion with respect to both secondaries while a current flows inside the string, When the string gets closer to one winding (lets call it the top winding) the magnetic flux will be stronger with respect to the top winding and weaker with respect to the bottom winding.
It will induce open circuits high voltages on both secondaries, with a slight differential due to the string vibration. so, now if i connect the two secondary windings in parallel; Such as the phase dots are opposed, I should see only the voltage differential due to the string position inside the window. Right ?
Now if the theory is valid, is it practical in terms of currents and voltages ? What preamp setup should I use ?
the core used is 85*50*30 (outside diameter*inside diameter*height in mm.) 26 turns gave me a value of 2.65 mH.
Any ideas ?

Comment: You will only get a small signal since most of the flux will be in the core and will not change much with wire position in the window.

Comment: ... and current transformers are insensitive to the position of the wires inside the core for this reason. If it were not so then the position of the wire inside the current transformer would be critical to taking accurate measurements but in practice it's not a problem.

Comment: So maybe using a pair of c cores forming an air gap would help ?

Comment: using a non-magnetic toroid (like a nylon washer, or a froot loop) would help,  or using a slotted toroid and having the wire inside the slot

Comment: ok, I will try this setup. Maybe a Helmoltz coil configuration with the wire passing in between would be the best, after all, simple air coils like these are used in metal detectors which are sensitive to positioning.